# Thymeleaf <select> tag generating options (numbers)

Tags: java, html, spring, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf

I have a `<select>` tag in HTML and need to generate options from 1 to 53 and then pick one I'm sending with the `doPost` method.

I tried to use the solution I found here: 
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/generating-content-for-select-programatically-td4024742.html,

```
<select name="week_scroll"
      style="width: 70px; height: 27px">
   <option 
       th:each="n : ${#numbers.sequence(1,53)"
       th:text="${n}"
   />
</select>
```

but I get an error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
Could not parse as each: "n : ${#numbers.sequence(1,53)"
```

also, what `th:` tag should I use to select from the list once it's been generated?

Comment: What version of thymeleaf are you using? I believe you need 2.1.3 for those utility class methods to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did't close the curly brace `}` of `th:each` attribute

It should be

Updated

```
<select name="week_scroll">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option th:each="n : ${#numbers.sequence(1,53)}" th:value="${n}" th:text="${n}"/>
</select>
```